# How do I fix the Mojang Native Launcher Updater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

[image: A screenshot of the popup]

Whenever I attempt to open Minecraft, I get the following error message: `Problem copying the file with the following error code: 2"` Also, the name of the popup window is "Mojang native launcher updater". I can temporarily solve this problem by turning off my WiFi, opening Minecraft, and quickly turning my WiFi back on, but the next time I reopen Minecraft, the same thing happens all over again.

When I searched for help online, I could only find it for error code 5. I have not been able to find a solution to this problem. I am running Minecraft on Windows 10, the launcher is version 1.6.11, and the version of Minecraft is 1.8.9. Also, I have installed (but am not using) forge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click, run as administrator. Fixed it for me, and further launches did not require admin rights.

Comment: Works like a charm!
Am I right to assume that the update needed to modify files in a protected folder (most likely Minecraft's subfolder in either Program Files or Program Filesx86)?

Comment: That's what I also suspect, and the reason I tried it in the first place.

Comment: Running as administrator ***does not work***. Do not try this. It proves ineffective as of October 27th, 2017.